# How to run external commands in vim from windows OS?

Tags: external-command, ctags

I learn vim in the Debian distro. In debian I can run commands like 'ls', 'cd', 'curl' etc directly from vim via power of '!' this sign. But now I am in windows because of the driver issue. But I don't able to use '!' this sign to run external commands direct form the vim. How to run external command within vim in windows os?

Comment: pls clarify why you are not able to use `!` on windows.

Comment: Could you also split your question 1. for external commands issue, 2. ctags on vim issue.

Comment: did you get an error message? If so, which one?

Answer (score 2):

To run external commands from within vim on windows you should use the same vim commands you use for other OSes.

```
:!dir
:echo system('dir')
```

Just to double check, `cmd.exe` that is used by default as a shell doesn't have `ls`, windows doesn't have `curl` and `ctags` unless you install them.

Comment: Power shell is the new cmd. Why I can't able to use those commands?

Comment: I guess you can if you make it your shell in vim `:set shell=powershell`

Comment: It works. What about vim tags. How to use it?

Comment: install universal-ctags and use it the same way you have used it in your debian?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to run a more complex command and it fails, with Vim you need to escape the character's it uses for running commands, i.e. `!`, `&`, and `#`. Use `shellescape` with `{special}` set to `1` to escape those chars with a backslash e.g.

```
let message = "Hello there!"
exe "!echo ".shellescape(message, 1)
```

See `:help shellescape`